# Controlling 230V LEDs with a single Z-Wave switch

Tags: led, parallel, series, home-automation, mains-supply

I am trying to control two 100W LED security lights via a motion sensor. The motion sensor is a Philips Hue and runs on the Zigbee network, the LED’s are 230V.

I have purchased a Raspberry Pi and installed home assistant so as to take the Zigbee signal from the sensor and then output a Z-Wave signal to a mains voltage Z-Wave controlled switch.

I am now trying to configure how I shall wire it up so I can purchase the wire and install it. I’m looking to run it through 1 mm^2 wiring, with Waco 32A 3-way connectors. The wiring will be open, in insulated - in the loft space.

When drawing how I planned to connect everything, I put the LEDs in parallel as I thought that would be best - as they would then both have 230V. From googling and reading numerous posts it appears that is a bad idea as I don’t want the LEDs to catch fire and burn my house down. I have read that they should be installed in series, but I am confused by this as though I understand that the current then remains constant - I am not understanding regarding the voltage drop as I understand the LEDs being in series would create a voltage divider and would then not provide the 230V required for the LEDs.

I have attached a photo of the two drawings I have made and hope I have made sense and would appreciate any help with this. If it is so that I should wire them in series, is my drawing correct? If it is not or if I should not then any advice is most gratefully received.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the 'bypass' device is - this appears to throw a dead short across the mains and is therefore a *bad idea*. Terminals on the ZW SW also don't seem  to be clear enough to ID. It doesn't seem like you're confident enough with mains wiring to be attempting this.

Comment: All joints or splices in mains cable need to be in suitable boxes and all mains cable outside boxes or conduits needs to be double insulated. It's not clear if you're achieving that.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica, those "bypass" devices, I suspect, are resistors to provide a path back to neutral for the Z-Wave switches whil they're off. They don't have a direct N connection.

Comment: hopefully bypass is something sensible like a lighting capacitor,

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica I appreciate it looks like it's dead short but it is on the switched output from the z-wave switch. It's purpose, according to the documentation provided is prevent flickering of the LED. In the UK cables are not double insulated, they are usually twin & earthed. I appreciate ensuring the integrity of the cores, but Wago connectors are also commonly used and comply with wiring legislation. Also, though I am not an electrician - I am more than competent enough to ensure I don't go touching live wires; I'm just not used to designing circuits.

Comment: @en_passant Twin and earth cable is double insulated so that's fine; I was just checking that you weren't intending to run single core cable around or make your joints outside boxes.

Comment: @en_passant If the 'Bypass' is a capacitor intended to be connected across mains, that's fine. It's not OK if it's a switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the series / parallel question:

> When drawing ... I put the LEDs in parallel as I thought that would be best - as they would then both have 230V.

Some of your confusion is that you are referring to LED lamp bulbs as "LEDs". The 230 V LED lamps consist internally of many LED in series along with the required power supply to enable continuous operation at the rated voltage, 230 V in this case.

> I have read that they should be installed in series, but I am confused by this as though I understand that the current then remains constant - I am not understanding regarding the voltage drop as I understand the LEDs being in series would create a voltage divider and would then not provide the 230V required for the LEDs.

[image]

*Figure 1. An LED mains lamp. Image source: [LEDnique](https://lednique.com/bulbs/dimmers-for-leds/).*

You will find that the LEDs are wired in series inside the lamp. (Brighter lamps may have parallel strings of series-connected LEDs.)

> I’m looking to run it through 1 mm<sup>2</sup> wiring, with Waco [Wago?] 32A 3-way connectors. The wiring will be open, in insulated - in the loft space.

1 mm<sup>2</sup> wiring would be adequate for lighting but may not be adequate for your local electrical insulation standards. I'm hoping that you mean, "The insulated wiring will be laid on top of the insulation in the loft space."

> I am trying to control two 100W LED security lights ...

100 W is very powerful for an LED lamp. I suspect that is their "equivalent incandescent bulb light output" and they probably consume < 20 W. Check the packaging.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful - the figure explains far better than I could find, so the floodlight is rectifying the 230V then supplying the individual LED's in series via the resistors. Re insulation: that was my phone auto-correcting which I didn't notice. The wiring will clipped in open air, NOT under insulation as above. I have checked the current rating of 1mm^2 and see it's adequate for this. The LED comes with 1m cable which has 1mm^2 cores. The floodlights are 2 of these [link] (https://v-tac.eu/discontinued/100w-led-floodlight-smd-samsung-chip-slim-black-body-white-detail.html)

Comment: OK, those are big lamps and they actually consume 100 W. Don't forget to click the "Solution" button on the best answer (but you can wait a couple of days to encourage other answers and viewpoints).

Answer (score 1):

230VAC lights are intended to be connected in parallel.  That's the way all lights in your house are wired.  LED lights are no exception.  They are made to be connected to the normal light switches in your house, wired as normal light bulbs are wired.

You'll need to be sure that your Z-Wave switches are rated to switch the sum of the power of the lights.  Two 100W bulbs on one switch means the switch must be rated for at least 200 watts.

---

The difficulties in connecting your lights to the Z-Wave switch have less to do with the technology and more to do with following the standards of the electrical wiring code of your country.

Those standards have to do with the safety of the wiring.  If you don't follow the standards, you may wire up something that works, but which may zap someone who touches something you didn't think to cover or insulate.  It may also overheat and catch on fire some night when you don't expect it.  Many of the things in the code are not obvious - they are requirements that come from observing things that went wrong (that no one expected) and then making regulations to reduce the chance that those things happen again.

Follow the standards.  If you don't know what they are and what you need to pay attention to, then you should either get an electrician to do it for you or at a minimum ask on the [DIY stack](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) how you should do it.  Someone there may also be able to point you at the appropriate wiring standards for your country or region.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Appreciate your safety notes also. The reason I wished to install the LED's in parallel was exactly for that reason: wouldn't be much use if lights were in series and one of them popped. I think my issue was in knowing what's going in within the floodlight itself. I had worked out I as 0.43A across one floodlight - the z-wave switch is rated for 1.4A capacitive loads (4.8A resistive).